# Display and access phone screen at laptop without configuring from the phone itself

Tags: display, android

I've a phone here that is working, but its display is damaged (my brother let it drop). I'm unable to even know its model, but it's basically a Samsung Galaxy... SM-A something (cannot read the model at all at its back), probably a J1 or J2 that comes with Android 5.x.

I've an USB-C to USB-A cable to use and a working laptop. Is there a way to access that phone from my laptop without configuring anything from the phone, since I've no idea where I'm touching?

Comment: No, there isn't. It always requires installing something in the phone and you can't because you have no user interface to do that. You could theoretically force install the required app from any computer with internet connection and accessing your Play Store but then you'd have to run it and set it up which, again, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method of doing this without requiring some prior configuration on the mobile device. There are various services, easily enough found via searches, that offer this function, but these will all require configuration on the mobile device before they can be used.